# How to remove count in layered navigation in Magento?

Tags: php, magento-1.8

I am using Magento 1.8.1 for my website tcollar.com. How to remove count in side bar left category in Magento?

Answer (score 10):

You can disable the count directly from the Admin Panel, without modifying any templates:

*System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> (Layered Navigation) -> Display Product Count*

Answer (score 2):

In filter.phtml go to below directory:
app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/layer/
Remove below code or comment:

```
(<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)
```